# Can Aura of Dominion be used with Inspire Creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I put [Aura of Dominion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aura%20of%20Dominion) on [Arbiter of the Ideal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arbiter%20of%20the%20Ideal), can I pay 1 mana and tap Arbiter of the Ideal (as the cost of Aura of Dominion's ability) and then have Arbiter untap (as the effect of Aura of Dominion's ability)?

If so, am I right in thinking that this will let me use Arbiter of the Ideal's Inspire ability as many times as I have untapped mana?

Comment: True, or until your top card is not a creature/land/artifact :p

Comment: Well, you can keep doing it. It just wouldn't do anything but repeatedly reveal the same card.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use Aura of Dominion to repeatedly trigger Inspired.

Basically, when you activate the ability, you tap the enchanted creature (and pay 1 mana) to pay for it. Then when it resolves, the enchanted creature untaps and the Inspired ability triggers. Then the game has basically returned to the state it started in, so you can do it until you run out of mana.